# aspx.net newbie: how to implement an Ajax clock and stopwatch?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Im trying to create two textboxes: one containing a simple clock and other containing a kind of stopwatch. I'm using a ScriptManager, a UpdatePannel and a Timer. But, this script is running on server, generating postbacks (I think), using bandwith and processing on server side. How can I implement this task using browser processing (like writting a java script on the page code)? - Later I'm going to store the stopwatch datum in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer in: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/280/javascript-to-display-time-on-web-page/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowTime() {

        var dt = new Date();

        document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").value = dt.toLocaleTimeString();

        window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);

    }  

</script>



<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>



<script type="text/javascript">

    // a startup script to put everything in motion

    window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);

</script>
```